# How do I enable Intel virtualization technology?

Tags: virtualization, bios

I need to check whether or not the Intel virtualization technology is enabled in my CPU. 
Problem is - when I open the BIOS setup I don't see anything about it. 
The BIOS version is : W7235IMS V1.9

Thanks

Comment: what CPU and what motherboard?

Comment: CPU:         Intel Core 2 Duo E4400
Motherboard: MS-7235

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can run this program:

```
ManagementClass managClass = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
ManagementObjectCollection managCollec = managClass.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject managObj in managCollec)
{
   foreach (var prop in managObj.Properties)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Property Name: {0} Value: {1}",prop.Name,prop.Value);
   }               
}
```

Look for a property called `VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled`. If you do not see it, then your processor doesn't have that feature.

You can also open a PowerShell window and execute this command:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_processor -Property name
```

Again, look for the property called `VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled`.

Comment: Hi I found the VirtualizationFirmwareEnabled property but there was no value. How do I determine if its on?

Answer (score 0):

This CPU (circa 2006) does Not support Vt-x.
http://ark.intel.com/products/29753/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E4400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB?q=Core%202%20Duo%20E4400